# Rails routing/limiting pages to a subdomain for subdomain based app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, subdomain

Im building a ruby on rails app with devise and subdomains.

- Each user has a username.myapp.ltd
- Each user has pages

I want to be able to only show and give access to pages for that specific user.

Currently /pages/id works no matter what user this page belongs to.

What would be the best way to route these pages and "lock" them under the user.username.ltd, only showing when they belong to that user?

My routes is like:

```
  constraints(Subdomain) do
    match '/' => 'frontend#show'
    resources :pages, :only => [:index, :show]
  end
```

Comment: DHH had a really good post on the 37signals blog about how to do this:[how-to-do-basecamp-style-subdomains-in-rails](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1512-how-to-do-basecamp-style-subdomains-in-rails) There's also this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3) that does exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: Are you looking to add security to your app so if someone goes to /pages/id and the id belongs to a different user they'll receive an error or be redirected?